# ¿Como distribuir un descuento en SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, while, update

tengo una consulta en cuanto a distribucion del siguiente codigo:

```
INSERT INTO CC_DETALLE_FACTURA(factura, serie, id_tipo_documento, codigo, descripcion, peso, valor, iva, valor_iva, documento_referencia, id_tipo_documento_referencia)  
  VALUES(  
   @factura,  
   @serie,  
   @id_tipo_documento,  
   @codigo,  
   @descripcion,  
   @peso,  
   @valor + @valoriva,  
   @valoriva,  
   @valoriva,  
   @documento_referencia,  
   @id_tipo_documento_referencia)  
     
  IF SUBSTRING(@codigo, 1, 3) = 'DES'  
  BEGIN  
  IF SUBSTRING(@codigo, 1, 3) = 'DES'   --@codigo = 'DES009'  
   BEGIN  
    DECLARE @id_detalle AS BIGINT  
   SET @id_detalle = (SELECT TOP 1 id_detalle_factura FROM CC_DETALLE_FACTURA WHERE factura = @factura AND serie = @serie AND ISNULL(peso, '0') <> '0' AND descuento = 0 AND codigo <> 'POB028') 
    UPDATE CC_DETALLE_FACTURA SET descuento = @valor + @valoriva, iva_descuento = @valoriva  
    WHERE id_detalle_factura = @id_detalle  
   END  
   
   SET @valor = @valor * -1  
   SET @valoriva = @valoriva * -1  
END  
  PRINT '1'
```

Es exactamente a la hora de aplicar ese descuento donde se le hace el update al mismo; mi problema radica que muchas veces este update se aplica al top 1 y como este sp le da el valor a los totales del encabezado lanza el error que no se puede aplicar el descuento asi que no se si hay algún metódo para hacer que el descuento se distribuya por codigos mayores a le mismo y no solo se vaya a aplicar a ala primera columna.